# How to enter hebrew with diacritics ("nikkud") in Windows?

Tags: windows, hebrew

How to enter hebrew with diacritics ("nikkud") in Windows?

Answer (score 5):

In Windows 8 to 10 there is another way to add "nikkud". When the language bar shows 'HE', all you need to do is press AltGr (or Alt+Ctrl) + the first letter of the "nikkud" name in Hebrew:

- ק = Kamatz
- פ = Patah
- ח = Hirik
- ס = Segol
- ד = Dagesh/Shuruk
- צ = Tzeire
- ו = Holam
- ' (w) = Right Shin
- / (q) = Left Shin
- \ = Kubbutz

The Hatafim are on the right of their vowels ("tnuot"):

- [ = Hataf Patah
- ר = Hataf Kamatz
- ב = Hataf Segol

There is an excellent software to add "nikkud" easily and quickly called [Rav-Nakad](http://nikkud.com/?page_id=576&lang=en).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the mnemonics and they save a ton of time!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are set to write in Hebrew, have caps-lock on, press shift and the numbers and signs keys (~ 1 ....9, 0 , - , =).

You write the diacritic sign after writing the letter itself.

There's also another way using Alt-GR and the numpad, but it is usually less comfortable and harder to remember what key combination gives you which sign.

See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/israel/support/tips/other/diacritics.mspx) for farther explanation and a map for which keys gives what signs.

Answer (score 1):

This is for Windows XP.  For Vista, the MSI won't install without admin rights.  Either disable UAC temporarily or create a batch file to execute the MSI and run the batch as admin.

- Download the [Ezra SIL Unicode Fonts 2.0](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/render_download.php?site_id=nrsi&format=file&media_id=EzrSIL20.zip&filename=EzrSIL20.zip) package.  The most recent package, v2.5 requires the Keyman program which is no longer free.  Extract the files.
- Execute `\Ezra SIL Release 2.0\Keyboards\Tiro Keyboards\BHebSIL.exe` to extract the keyboard files.
- Execute `\Ezra SIL Release 2.0\Keyboards\Tiro Keyboards\BHebSIL.msi` to install the keyboard file.
- Start -> Run -> `intl.cpl` -> Languages tab -> Details -> Add
- For **Input language:** select Hebrew.  For **Keyboard layout/IME:** select Biblical Hebrew (SIL).  Click OK.
- Start -> Run -> `control fonts`.  Drag the files in `\Ezra SIL Release 2.0\Fonts\` into the font window to install them.

Now when you select the font Ezra SIL in your word processor and switch to Hebrew language (<kbd>ALT</kbd>־<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>), you will be able to enter the accents as you type.  Refer to `\Ezra SIL Release 2.0\Keyboards\Tiro Keyboards\BiblicalHebrew(SIL)Manual.pdf` pages 7-10 for the keyboard maps.

I've found this to be the fastest and easiest way to write Hebrew for any serious length with cantillation marks.  I opted for the BHebSIL keyboard over BHebTiro b/c I find BHebSIL to be more intuitive; the vowel pointings match their rough english equivalent key without needing to hit shift: patah to A, segol to E, etc.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid having to keep CapsLock on, you can create a custom keyboard. Using Microsoft keyboard layout creator, you can create a custom keyboard that allows you to type quickly and efficiently in Hebrew with nikkud.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

In Windows 8 to 10 there is another way to add "nikkud". When the language is set to Hebrew/עברית (standard), all you need to do is press AltGr (or Alt+Ctrl) + the first letter of the "nikkud" name in Hebrew:

- קָ E = Kamatz
- ַפ P = Patah
- ִח J = Hirik
- ֶס X = Segol
- ּד S = Dagesh/Shuruk
- ֵצ M = Tzeire
- ֹו U = Holam
- שְ A = Shva
- ' (W) = Right Shin (שׁ)
- / (Q) = Left Shin (שׂ)
- \ = Kubbutz (וֻ)

The Hatafim are on the right of their vowels ("tnuot"):

- [ = Hataf Patah (פֲ)
- ר R = Hataf Kamatz (רֳ)
- ב C = Hataf Segol (בֱ)

If you have the language set to Hebrew/עברית [it will just say that, it will not say (standard)] then it is the caplocks + shift method with the top row on the keyboard (numerals ~,1,2...,0,_,+)

Comment: Thank you very much. On a Win10 machine that First Letter method worked and all the other ones I tried, Capslock Shift etc. with numerals did not work.

Comment: Is this documented somewhere? I searched and searched and only found this here.

Answer (score 0):

this worked great, until some misclick caused windows to print a Tzeire under the X too, instead of a segol.  How can the error be fixed so that segol is printed again and so restore the windows to make the nikud in the manner described above?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).